# Problem of undefined element when i use map in the component ti show the lists of missions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is my code:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({      
MissionList: state.Mission.MissionList,   
isLoadingListMission:state.Mission.isLoadingListMission,    }); 
  
const mapDispatchToProps =  (dispatch) => ({   getMissionExpertById:
(id) =>  dispatch(actions.getMissionExpertById(id)), });

      {MissionList.data.map((el) => {
        return (
          <div key={el.key}>
            <p>{el.title}</p>
          </div>
        );  })}
```

**action.js**

```
import { getStatusError } from '../../../utils/helpres'; import
 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'; import { apiCall } from
 '../../../js/actions';
 
 const getMissionExpertById = (id) => async (dispatch) => {  
 dispatch({ type: 'GET_MISSION_REQUEST_REQUESTING' });   try {
     const url = `api/quote/request/:type`;
     const { data } = await apiCall({
       method: 'get',
       url,
     });
     dispatch({ type: 'GET_MISSION_REQUEST_SUCCESS', data: data.data });   } catch (err) {
     const { response } = err;
     if (response)
       dispatch({
        type: 'GET_MISSION_REQUEST_FAILURE',
         err: err.message,
         status: getStatusError(err),
       });   } };
 
 export default {   getMissionExpertById, };
```

**reducers.js**

```
const  initialAppState = {   isLoadingListMission: false,   listMission:[],
 }; const MissionRequestReducer = (state = initialAppState, action) =>
 {   switch (action.type) {
     case 'GET_MISSION_REQUEST_REQUESTING':
       return {
         ...state,
         isLoadingListMissione: true,
       };
     case 'GET_MISSION_REQUEST_SUCCESS':
       return {
         ...state,
         isLoadingListMission: false,
         listMission: action.data,
       };
     case 'GET_MISSION_REQUEST_FAILURE':
       return {
         ...state,
         isLoadingListMission: false,
         listMission: null,
       };
     default: {
       return state;
     }   } };
 
 export default MissionRequestReducer;
```

What is the problem, please?

[image]

Comment: I did my best to fix the formatting, but can't... Can you please format your question and codeappropriately?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to bellow and use `optional chaining`:

```
 {MissionList?.data?.map((el) => {
   return (
     <div key={el.key}>
       <p>{el.title}</p>
      </div>
    );  })}
```